# word mail merge - importing data from excel to word checkbox/drop down fields

Tags: form-fields

I have a word form with checkboxes and drop down list…is there a way to import data from a excel spreadsheet…we plan on sending these out and need the fields in end product to be active so clients can change anything that is wrong (choose the right answer from the drop down list, check or uncheck boxes)

Comment: Share the code you have tried so far...

Comment: That is the problem…I have been using mail merge which does't work…no options to tell it to check the box or choose a value from a drop down menu...